# BackgroundWorker not exiting loop

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have an BackgroundWorker:
`BackgroundWorker worker;`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.ProgressChanged += 
          new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
         new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
}
```

DoWork Event

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
int percentFinished = (int)e.Argument;
while (!worker.CancellationPending && percentFinished < 100)
{
 percentFinished++;
 worker.ReportProgress(percentFinished);

 //here I start my operation
 //operation....
 //operation end

}
e.Result = percentFinished;
}
```

Progresschanged

```
void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Completed

```
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Asynchroner Thread kam bis zum Wert:
"+e.Result.ToString());
btnStartEnd.Text = "Starten";
}
```

And finally my button:

```
private void btnStartEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (worker.IsBusy)
   {
   worker.CancelAsync();
   btnStartEnd.Text = "Starten";
   }
else
   {
     if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
      {
      progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
      }
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(progressBar1.Value);
    btnStartEnd.Text = "Stoppen";
   }
}
```

This code works but I get a loop for my operations until the percentage is 100, so the operation starts 100 times and so takes 100 times longer.

The goal should be that the operation only starts one time and the percentage counts from 1-100.

Maybe I understand something wrong, but how does the worker know how far the operation is done? That value should be send to the progress bar for visualisation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to answer your question is to know exactly what is happening in your operation (which in the question is represented only by comments). For sure, you don't want to loop 100 times just for the sake of progress. But you need for the operation itself to have meaningful intervals where progress can be reported. Nothing in your question shows how that might work, since it includes no details at all about the operation itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you won’t add the loop inside the DoWork method
If you want to load for example 100 files from the file system and report the progress it could look like that:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // Load file and do something with the content
        ...
        // Report the progress which causes the ProgressChanged event to be fired
        // And update progressbar with the UI thread
        worker.ReportProgress(i);                   
    }
}
```

If you only have one long running operation that needs to be executed inside the DoWork method it needs to be executed asynchronously

Here is one example how you could call an action asynchronously in .NET:

```
Action action = () =>
{
    for(int i = 0; i <100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Step {0} of long running operation", i));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
};

var r = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);
while(!r.IsCompleted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

However in .NET there are many more ways to do it. See for example:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx for
  Async patterns in .NET
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh191443.aspx for Async
  programming with await/async (new in .NET 4.5)

Comment: Thanks that's clear. I have only one long running operation so how can I execute it asynchronously with the return for the progressbar so that my form is still running?

Comment: I extended the answer a little bit to include a simple example of how to call a method asynchronously

Comment: @katz *I have only one long running operation so how can I execute it asynchronously with the return for the progressbar so that my form is still running?* The `DoWork` method is already executed asynchronously with respect to the UI thread. If you can't divide the operation into smaller pieces or somehow provide an estimate of the progress then you're simply out of luck and you can only show some "work in progress" animation.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe I understand something wrong, but how does the worker know how far the operation is done? That value should be send to the progress bar for visualisation.

The `BackgroundWorker` class doesn't know anything about your operations and about its progress. It's your job to determine when to report the progress.

In general the workflow for a background worker looks like this:

- UI thread calls `RunWorkerAsync`.
- `DoWork` event handler is called on a different thread. During the event handler you can report progress using the `ReportProgress` method
- If you report a progress then the `ProgressChanged` event handler is called on the UI thread. Here you can update a progress bar for example.
- When your event handler for the `DoWork` event exits the `RunWorkerComplete` event is raised.

Now why does every example for the `BackgroundWorker` has a for-loop? Because it's very easy to write, and measuring progress for a for-loop is trivial. Unfortunately this quite often isn't useful for different kind of operations.

If your long running operation processes N files then it's pretty obvious that you can update the progress bar after every item by 1/N. That's what the for-loop example does.

But if you only have one long running operation then you simply don't have any chance to get the progress *unless* the operation itself supports reporting it or if you can somehow estimate the progress.

The `BackgroundWorker` can't magically give a long running operation a progress bar. It only enables you to run the operation in the background.